# React Router Link's dynamic param not in props.match

Tags: react-router

I'm trying to build a small blog site. When navigating from a post's detailed page to the author's profile, I pass the user's id to the link.

```
<Link to={"/userPage/" + this.state.post.userId}>{this.state.post.userName}</Link>
```

The Route looks like this:

```
<Route path="/userPage/:id" exact component={UserPage}/>
```

This all works perfectly fine.
However, in my navbar I have a 'My Profile' link, which looks like this (the logged-in user's details are also stored in the browser's local storage):

```
<Link to={"/userPage/" + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).id}>My Profile</button>
```

If I'm currently on a different user's profile page and want to navigate from the navbar to my own profile page, the browser's url bar shows the correct link (with my user id), but when I check this.props.match.params.id, it still has the previous user's id in it, until I click the 'My Profile' link for the second time. Could anyone tell me why this happens and how I can synchronize these events? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the solution, I was using a premature lifecycle method to get the param from the props and update the page (componentWillUpdate). When using componentDidUpdate, as the name suggests, the component's details have already been updated and I can get the new props (and fetch data accordingly).